# Change ugly query string to a prettier /path/to/page/ pattern

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have a site which uses a custom query string to deliver pages to the visitor. A sample query string looks like `/?sec=news&pg=current&bg=203`. I'd like to use `.htaccess` to rewrite the strings into a pattern like `/news/current/203`.

I know how to take the `/news/current/203` URL and make it into a query string that I can parse with PHP. I typically use this bit of htaccess code:

````
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?id=$1 [L]```
````

And my PHP then explodes `id` on the `/` and off we are running.

My question is this... How can I add a few more lines to this htaccess code that will allow the old URL query pattern to continue to work for people that have bookmarks or links that use the `/?sec=news...` pattern? Basically, it seems like I need to take this old query string and combine the values into one string that I can pass to index.php in the `id` parameter. I don't want to lose the ability to honor the old pattern, but also need to promote the new cleaner path-based string.

I know there is some regex that can help here, but I am terrible at understanding regular expressions. Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if I am not making any sense.

---

Update: The answer provided makes my final htaccess file look like this...

```
RewriteEngine on

# Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes

# Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sample.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

# WHEN DONE TESTING< CHANGE ALL 302 to 301 !!!
# Honor the old format /index.php?sec=XXX&pg=XXX&bg=XXX and turn it into the new format
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sec=(\w+)&pg=(\w+)&bg=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]

# Turn /path/to/page into index.php?id=path/to/page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sec=(\w+)&pg=(\w+)&bg=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]
```

Change 302 to 301

Comment: It looks so simple when someone else does it... thanks, I will try that out today and report on the outcome.

Comment: It works just as you said it would. I do have a follow up question, though... The htaccess is rewriting `?sec=projects` to `/projects/` like I want. I also have `Options All -Indexes` in there to prevent directory listing. I have a folder on the server called `projects`, though, and it has no index file inside, which would be a problem... but even still, I am getting a "Forbidden" error at `/projects/`, I am guessing because I can't have an actual folder and a URL that I am reading with PHP exist at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I recommend to move that folder or change its name